# Controller for serving images doesn't work with extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to serve my images by using an ImageController:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    // GET: Image
    public ActionResult Render(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(/*some path*/);
        return this.Image(image, "image/png");
    }
}
```

I added the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Images",
    url: "images/{action}/{fileName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Image", action = "Render", fileName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So this image path works:
http://xxx.xxx/images/render/x

But a path with this extension doesn't:
http://xxx.xxx/images/render/x**.png**

A "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error appears.

What should I do to enable file extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1. Enable custom file routing inside RouteConfig.cs

   ```
   routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
   ```
2. Add the following handler inside your web.config

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ProtectedImages" path="images/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"   preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```